# How to add repeating text that you know will change later

Tags: microsoft-word, paste

I use Paste Special (Paste Link) when I am repeating text in Excel 2010, but I can't find a similar function in Word.

I need to be able to paste text in several areas of a document, and then update it once and have the update appear throughout the document.  Excel allows me to do that with Paste Special.

What is the function in Word 2010?  Quick Parts allows me to save blocks of text, but I can't change the text, so that doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `Bookmarks`.

To create a bookmark;

1. Highlight the word you want to repeat.
2. Click `Insert`, `Links`, `Bookmark`.
3. In the Bookmark window, name it as you wish, then click <kbd>Add</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

To use the bookmark to repeat the word;

1. Place your cursor where you want the word repeated.
2. Click `Insert`, `Links`, `Cross-reference`.
3. In the Cross-reference window select `Bookmark` for the reference
   type.
4. Select the bookmark for the word you want to reuse.
5. Click <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

To change the word, update the bookmark, select all text and press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all the cross-references.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this video, it's got the best solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwPQg6sQ9jo

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.